# Menu material desing

Tags: android

Как сделать вот такое меню? Это явно не PopupMenu и не Spinner, так что же это?
https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/menus.html#menus-usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это `overflow menu`, я делаю так:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    SubMenu sub = menu.addSubMenu("").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_overflow);
    sub.add(Menu.NONE, 0, Menu.NONE, "Пунтк1").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_1);
    sub.add(Menu.NONE, 1, Menu.NONE, "Пункт2").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_2);
    sub.add(Menu.NONE, 2, Menu.NONE, "Пункт3").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_3);

    MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(sub.getItem(),MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 0: {} break;
        case 1: {} break;
        case 2: {} break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Вот это меню которое описано здесь, что то не похоже на вложенное меню или overflow menu или оно какое то кастомное?-https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/menus.html#menus-usage  "The label of an emitting button or control concisely and accurately reflects the menu item ...."  Потому что оно располагается ниже разделов самого меню и имеет в себе несколько разделов.

Comment: не работает без return и с ним тоже.     onCreateOptionsMenu

Comment: @semiromid этот код для фрагмента, для активити этот метод выглядит так:  `public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`, по поводу внешнего вида, если использовать `support library(appcompat)`, то меню будет выглядеть абсолютно так же.

Comment: katso спасибо. Я так и думал что внешний вид зависит от версии ОС. Наверное тогда я буду использовать PopupWindow, он все таки более кастомный.

Comment: katso - Я использую -  com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1' ---android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  Но даже если запускать на 5.0 ОС андроид, то панелька все равно находится не снизу самих пунктов, а прямо на самом пунке из которого её вызывают. Вывод - версия ОС не причем.

Answer (score 2):

Можно прямо из xml задать:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:id="@+id/file"
              android:icon="@drawable/file"
              android:title="@string/file" >
            <!-- "file" submenu -->
            <menu>
                <item android:id="@+id/create_new"
                      android:title="@string/create_new" />
                <item android:id="@+id/open"
                      android:title="@string/open" />
            </menu>
        </item>
    </menu>
```

Comment: Вот это меню которое описано здесь, что то не похоже на вложенное меню или overflow menu или оно какое то кастомное?-google.com/design/spec/components/menus.html#menus-usage "The label of an emitting button or control concisely and accurately reflects the menu item ...." Потому что оно располагается ниже разделов самого меню и имеет в себе несколько разделов.